# Tooltip hover only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to jquery. I've been trying to use this code below to have a tooltip come in on hover. It works, but the problem is that it only works one time. Once I take the mouse off and back on, the title doesn't display and only shows a small blank box.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/iuw14ew/VSQma1786/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js"></script>

<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[title]").style_my_tooltips({
            tip_follows_cursor:true,
            tip_delay_time:90,
            tip_fade_speed:600,
            attribute:"title"
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Additional Scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.documentElement.className += ' js';</script>
<!-- JS includes -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="scripts/html5shiv.js?4241844378" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('\x3Cscript src="' + (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//use.typekit.net/ik/F2hE6cJdmyh1_kUm5EU4iL8edw7_cfPZzq2fG5LIbCvfe7JgfwKSEMIPH2wtw2baF2sL52SkwcJX5eJhZQq3FeJujRIawRwuFeZ8ZeJtFeIhwAb-HABlZW4TjhNDZAU8jaszSKoRdhXCHKoydAmk-AFzShmCZAFXdaJ0jhNlJ6N3Scm0ieN0OAsTSagCjWqKI1gySc8D-Ao8OWFXZfuRdeBTSKG4fFjUIMMjMPMfH6qJoh6bMs6YJM4HgIuuShAbMZHrNOIB.js" type="text/javascript">\x3C/script>');</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { try {
(function(){var a={},b=function(a){if(a.match(/^rgb/))return
a=a.replace(/\s+/g,"").match(/([\d\,]+)/gi)[0].split(","),(parseInt(a[0])<<16)+(parseInt(a[1])<<8)+parseInt(a[2]);if(a.match(/^\#/))return parseInt(a.substr(1),16);return 0};(function(){$('link[type="text/css"]').each(function(){var b=($(this).attr("href")||"").match(/\/?css\/([\w\-]+\.css)\?(\d+)/);b&&b[1]&&b[2]&&(a[b[1]]=b[2])})})();(function(){$("body").append('<div class="version" style="display:none; width:1px; height:1px;"></div>');
for(var c=$(".version"),d=0;d<Muse.assets.required.length;){var f=Muse.assets.required[d],g=f.match(/([\w\-\.]+)\.(\w+)$/),k=g&&g[1]?g[1]:null,g=g&&g[2]?g[2]:null;switch(g.toLowerCase()){case "css":k=k.replace(/\W/gi,"_").replace(/^([^a-z])/gi,"_$1");c.addClass(k);var g=b(c.css("color")),h=b(c.css("background-color"));g!=0||h!=0?(Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1),"undefined"!=typeof a[f]&&(g!=a[f]>>>24||h!=(a[f]&16777215))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.push(f)):d++;c.removeClass(k);break;case "js":k.match(/^jquery-[\d\.]+/gi)&&
typeof $!="undefined"?Muse.assets.required.splice(d,1):d++;break;default:throw Error("Unsupported file type: "+g);}}c.remove();if(Muse.assets.outOfDate.length||Muse.assets.required.length)c="Some files on the server may be missing or incorrect. Clear browser cache and try again. If the problem persists please contact website author.",(d=location&&location.search&&location.search.match&&location.search.match(/muse_debug/gi))&&Muse.assets.outOfDate.length&&(c+="\nOut of date: "+Muse.assets.outOfDate.join(",")),d&&Muse.assets.required.length&&(c+="\nMissing: "+Muse.assets.required.join(",")),alert(c)})()})();
/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblemsPreInit();/* body */
Muse.Utils.prepHyperlinks(true);/* body */
Muse.Utils.initWidget('.MenuBar', function(elem) { return $(elem).museMenu(); });/* unifiedNavBar */
Muse.Utils.resizeHeight()/* resize height */
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#accordionu22152', function(elem) { return new WebPro.Widget.Accordion(elem, {canCloseAll:true,defaultIndex:-1}); });/* #accordionu22152 */
Muse.Utils.fullPage('#page');/* 100% height page */
Muse.Utils.showWidgetsWhenReady();/* body */
Muse.Utils.transformMarkupToFixBrowserProblems();/* body */
} catch(e) { if (e && 'function' == typeof e.notify) e.notify(); else Muse.Assert.fail('Error calling selector function:' + e); }});
```

Comment: working for me , did u check it on multiple browser ?

Comment: Works for me, too. Tested in Firefox and Chrome. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/edLm0eam/1)

Comment: Works for me well...

Comment: Do you have any other JS on the page?

Comment: Seth - Yes I do. Added to the post.